# Using a Posterior as a Prior - A Rose by Any Other Name

Tags: bayesian

One response to [In Stan is there a way to use parameter posterior from old analysis as prior in new analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241690/in-stan-is-there-a-way-to-use-parameter-posterior-from-old-analysis-as-prior-in) was

> Possible ways around it are to refit the model with all data or to
>   approximate the posterior with e.g. some mixture distribution (e.g. of
>   bivariate normals to $\mu$ and $\log\sigma$ - e.g. in R using e.g. the mclust
>   package or in SAS using PROC FMM) and to use the mixture log-pdf as
>   the new prior.

Does the "posterior-used-as-a-prior" have a concise name?

Comment: I guess, a Bayesian by heart could say that every prior is a posterior of something.

Comment: Perhaps, but I am looking for a concise name for a prior that was derived from the posterior of a previous Bayesian analysis as described in the cited response, i.e., I fit a distribution to the posterior of one analysis and then used it as a prior for the next analysis.

Comment: The concise name is 'prior'.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically the Bayes theorem, which acts as an "Actualization Principle". See page 9 of the book by @Xi'an:

> The Bayesian Choice: A Decision-Theoretic Motivation.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the book by Christian P. Robert?

Comment: Yes, Xi'an is his user ID here.